# Libphonenumber parse Ireland toll free number

Tags: java, phone-number, libphonenumber

When getting the national prefix of an IE number, I get back nothing. This is the method that I'm using:

```
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();

public static String getPrefix(Phonenumber.PhoneNumber phoneNumber) throws NumberParseException {
    int nationalCodeLength = phoneUtil.getLengthOfNationalDestinationCode(phoneNumber);
    String significantNumber = phoneUtil.getNationalSignificantNumber(phoneNumber);
    String destinationCode = "";
    if (nationalCodeLength > 0) {
        destinationCode = significantNumber.substring(0, nationalCodeLength);
    }
    return destinationCode;
}
```

The method returns the empty string when passing `+353800844561` (valid toll free Ireland number) to it. I would expect the method to return `800`

The method returns `7984` when passing `+447984612345` (valid UK mobile number).

I have read about other people issues with IE numbers, but so far, I haven't found/came up with a solution in Java to this problem.

What could be the issue and/or fix here?

Comment: You provided a method that refers to undefined methods here, you should provide more details.
For example what's phoneUtil ? a Library ? utility class in your project ?

Comment: PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance(); rest of the methods are part of the libphonenumber api